# My form asks for an Investment Amount of at least 50000 but no matter what the input is error message is sent

Tags: python

In my form I ask for an Investment Amount and it should be at least $50,000. When I test if it works (see below), no matter what a person puts in it still says Investment Amount Must Be At Least $50,000:

```
investor = get_string("Investment: ")

investment = int()
if (investment < 50000):
    print("Investment Amount Must Be At Least 50000!")
else:
    print("OK")
```

~/project/ $ python test.py
Investment: 60000
Investment Amount Must Be At Least 50000!

Answer (score 0):

`investment = int()` is creating a new int object with default value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the line:

```
investment = int()
```

Here's the fixed code:

```
investment = int(input("Investment: "))


if (investment < 50000):
    print("Investment Amount Must Be At Least 50000!")
else:
    print("OK")
```

Edit: The top line was also off, when I tried your original code, get_string was giving me a Name Error.

Comment: Thank all of you for helping me resolve this issue.  It is working now.  Again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The int() function returns an integer object constructed from a number or string , or return 0 if no arguments are given. Since investment is zero, the condition is executed always. Try to get get the input and then compare.

```
investment = int(input("Enter Investment Amount"))

if (investment < 50000):
    print("Investment Amount Must Be At Least 50000!")
else:
    print("OK")
```